# find string in particular array

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading contents of a file and exploding into an array 
After reversing the array, Please help to find the first occurrence of END and store all data into a variable. Plus, please help to get the second occurrence of END.

```
function get(){

    $path="C:/xampp/htdocs/test/recentOrders.txt";
    if(!file_exists($path)){
        echo "Error";   
    }else {
        $summary= file_get_contents($path);

        $summaryarr = explode("\n", $summary);

        $summaryarrR=array_reverse($summaryarr);
        foreach($summaryarrR as $a){
        echo $a."<br>";
    }
    if (in_array('END', $summaryarrR)) {
        echo "Got mac";
    } else { echo "not found"; }

    $key=array_search('END', $summaryarrR); 
    var_dump($key);
}
```

File contents are as follows:

```
END 07/10/2014 10:30:15
52970 10024
52970 10024
52970 10024
END 07/10/2014 10:50:36
52970 10025
52970 10025
```

Comment: what are you trying to extract anyway? the dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shortened my code a bit to just include the important parts to get you you're result here.
This will loop through your array, and du a substr() to check if the first three letters of the array object is "END". If it matches, it will add the current array key to a new arary named $ends. This will finally contain all of the array keys containing and END-element. To get the first occurence, just use $ends[0]:

```
$summary= file_get_contents($path);

$summaryarr = explode("\n", $summary);

$i=0;
$ends = array();
while( $i < count( $summaryarr ) ){
    echo $summaryarr[$i] . "<br>";
    if( substr( $a, 0, 3 ) == "END" ){
        $ends[] = $i;
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r( "ends occur on array keys: " . $ends );
```

Answer (score -1):

Copied from W3C

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

Comment: You answer is javascript, whilst the OP code is in PHP

Comment: Use in_array() Function [Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: in array wont work, because the array element itself doesnt contain only "END". It contains "END <unknown variable>". in_array() checks for an exact match.